# No resource found that matches the given name in common_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play-services, monogame

I am developing a MonoGame app (C#) for Android using Xamarin Android in VS2012. Everything was going well then on a particular build I suddenly started getting 4 similar errors for no apparent reason. These errors all originate from the [Google Play component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservicesgingerbread) found in the Xamarin component store:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark').
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light').
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark').
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light').
```

These all occur within

> Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android\16\content\google-play-services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_light.xml

I am not sure what triggered these errors to suddenly popup after I have been using this component for a while. I also don't know how to get rid of them.

My project compiles using Android version 2.3, API Level 10. The min target is also v2.3 API level 10, and the target version is set to v4.4 API 19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Go to the
>   Components\googleplayservicesgingerbread-16.0.0.1\lib\android and
>   delete (or rename) the 16 folder. When you rebuild the content will be
>   downloaded again and the files should be there.
>
> I would keep this project closer to the root of your disk. MAX_PATH
>   issues are common when using the GooglePlay component.
>
> I can not imagine why these four files are missing, but once you
>   replace them it should work.

- Xamarin support email that fixed the issue

Comment: How can I get to this folder? (I'm using Xamarin Studio, it doesn't show up as a openable folder)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a path issue, could you move your project as close to c:\ root to see if that helps.

You are likely to hit the maximum path length on windows.

Answer (score 1):

This tends to happen when the user hits the maximum path error.

After ensuring the maximum file path will not be exceeded, uninstall and re-install the package (or component).

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979768/drawable-resource-files-not-found-for-google-play-component/24815642#24815642)

**Note:** - I would have added this as a comment to your answer which guided me to my solution, but currently lack the reputation as I'm typically a troller rather than poster.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to compile the app using Android 4.3+ and set minimum target version to v2.3 API Level 10

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I did install the v2.3 Google Play component so it should and did work when compiling with v2.3. I just cant figure what suddenly triggered these errors.